# Android - Parse web content

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android. I'm trying to make an app that gets the source code of a web page, gets the urls of all the images in it and their titles ad displays it in an image view.
While I'm able to get the source code, the text I get seems to be some kind of fused text and so I'm unable to find the urls in the text. 
What should I do to get an expanded version of the source code.

'''

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<Bitmap> imageSet;
    ArrayList<String> names;

    String sourceCode;

    protected class SourceCodeDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String >{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection;
            try {
                 url= new URL(urls[0]);
                 connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data= reader.read();
                while(data!=-1){
                    sourceCode+=(char)data;
                    data=reader.read();
                }

                return sourceCode;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }


    protected class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap >{

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                URL url= new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap img= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                return img;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageSet= new ArrayList<>(); names= new ArrayList<>(); sourceCode="";
        SourceCodeDownloader sourceCodeDownloader= new SourceCodeDownloader();
        try {
            sourceCode=sourceCodeDownloader.execute("https://www.ranker.com/list/forbes-100-most-powerful-celebrities/worlds-richest-people-lists").get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
        Pattern p= Pattern.compile("<img src=\"(.*?)\"");
        Pattern q= Pattern.compile("title=\"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher m=p.matcher(sourceCode);
        Matcher n=q.matcher(sourceCode);
        ImageDownloader imageDownloader= new ImageDownloader();
        while(m.find()){
                try {
                    Bitmap img= imageDownloader.execute(m.group(1)).get();
                    imageSet.add(img);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        while(n.find()) {
            try {
                String name = m.group(1);
                names.add(name);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        */

        Log.i("done", sourceCode);
        /*
        Log.i("done", String.valueOf(imageSet.size())+" "+String.valueOf(names.size()));
        */


    }
}

'''
```

This is the log I get. Basically, I get all the heading of the source code but the subheadings are missing and thus I can't get my desired image url.
What should I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
     /$$$$$$$                      /$$
    | $$__  $$                    | $$
    | $$  \ $$  /$$$$$$  /$$$$$$$ | $$   /$$  /$$$$$$   /$$$$$$
    | $$$$$$$/ |____  $$| $$__  $$| $$  /$$/ /$$__  $$ /$$__  $$
    | $$__  $$  /$$$$$$$| $$  \ $$| $$$$$$/ | $$$$$$$$| $$  \__/
    | $$  \ $$ /$$__  $$| $$  | $$| $$_  $$ | $$_____/| $$
    | $$  | $$|  $$$$$$$| $$  | $$| $$ \  $$|  $$$$$$$| $$
    |__/  |__/ \_______/|__/  |__/|__/  \__/ \_______/|__/
     -->
    <html lang="en" xmlns:og="//opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="//www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> <head> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//prd.rnkr-static.com/146"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//api.ranker.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://imgix.ranker.com"/> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//imgix.ranker.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://polyfill.io"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//assets.adobedtm.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.google-analytics.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.facebook.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.googletagmanager.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//content.jwplatform.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//pixel.quantserve.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//cdn.yldbt.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//www.googletagservices.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ox-d.ranker.servedbyopenx.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//apex.go.sonobi.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//ib.adnxs.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//assets.pinterest.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="cdn.petametrics.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="www.youtube.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//adserver.adtechus.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//btlr.sharethrough.com"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cdn.rebel.ai"> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://secure.rebel.ai"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//prd.rnkr-static.com/146"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//api.ranker.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="https://imgix.ranker.com"/> <link rel="preconnect" href="//imgix.ranker.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> <link rel="preconnect" href="https://polyfill.io" crossorigin> <link rel="preconnect" href="//assets.adobedtm.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//www.google-analytics.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//s3.amazonaws.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//sync.bfmio.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//beacon.krxd.net"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//pre.ads.justpremium.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//pixel.quantserve.com"> <link rel="preconnect" href="//secure.quantserve.com"> <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width"/> <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=contain"/> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png"/> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/touch-icon-iphone.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/touch-icon-ipad.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png"> <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png"> <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#1E3E66"/> <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/msapplication-square150x150logo.png"/> <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/> <!-- Open Graph Metadata --> <title>The Power 100 | Forbes 100 Most Powerful Celebrities </title> <meta name="description" content="The Power 100 list from Forbes contains the 100 most powerful people in Hollywood and the highest paid celebrities. The richest actors, actresses and media power players are here. These are the top richest people in the world of entertainment. M
```

Comment: How are you defining "images". There are no URL which ends with `.jpg`or `.png` or some other extension in you code. Or you pasted only part of the conent.

Comment: You should look at the source code of a scrapping repository coded in java on GitHub.

Comment: I m supposed to get the URL of the image from the webpage (whose URL is specified).

Comment: I'm reading web scrapping in java is done by jsoup. Is that something I should look into?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use Jsoup library, and here's an example of how to get all images with **trending__image** as a name of class

```
 String URL = "https://www.ranker.com/";


 @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Integer, List<String>, List<String>> {
        Document doc = null;
        ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(final Integer... integers) {

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (doc != null) {
                Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("trending__image");
                for (Element element : elements) {
                    String url = element.attr("src");
                    urls.add(url);
                }
            }
            return urls;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> urls) {
            super.onPostExecute(urls);
            //
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all of the URLs you can use simple regex:

```
 data-src=\"(.+?)\" class=
```

So here is the code collecting all of the urls:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(" data-src=\"(.+?)\" class=");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();

while (matcher.find()) {
    String url = matcher.group(1);
    urls.add(url);
}

// Remove the last one (containg rest of the input)
urls.remove(urls.size() - 1);

// Show urls
for (String url : urls) {
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

Comment: Hey, so what this regex is doing is getting all URLS from the content. I get that. My trouble is when I'm getting the said content from web, it is somehow a shorten version and doesn't contain the URLS. Thank you!